# Login Validation Returning 0 When It Should Not

Tags: php, mysql

So I've got a database called movierating with the table users, in there Ive got a primary key: user_id, and a user_name and user_password parameters. I want to complete my login system and cant really find an answer to my problem. The thing is I've added an "user" in my db with the username: test and password: test .
It will always return 0 even tho I know I've got the user registered.

```
    <?php
/** 
    Data: 29-10-2017
    Ficheiro de configuração, cria e seleciona a base de dados 
*/

/* 
    Definição das constantes para acesso à base de dados. Pretende-se que estas informações não
    sejam alteradas por qualquer script deste site.
*/
define('DB_USER', 'root');      // nome do utilizador com acesso à base de dados
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');  // password de acesso à base de dados       
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');     // nome do servidor
define('DB_NAME', 'movierating');       // nome da base de dados

// Ligação ao servidor MySQL
$con =  new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($con->connect_errno){
    echo "Falhou a conexão com a base de dados: " . $dbc->connect_errno;
}

$con->set_charset("utf8"); // permite corrigir os caracteres com cedilhas na visualização dos campos

    ?>
```

This is my connection to my database.
And this is my login validation:

```
    <?php

    require_once "ligaDB.php";

    if(isset($_POST['send'])){

if(isset($_POST['username'])) $user  = $_POST['username'];
if(isset($_POST['password'])) $senha  = $_POST['password'];
    }

$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name
        FROM users
        WHERE user_name='$user' AND user_password=SHA1('$senha')";

$result = $con->query($sql);

if($con->errno) die($dbc->error);

if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    // utilizador está registado

    // Extrai o registo 
    $registo = $result->fetch_assoc();     //$registo = $result->fetch_array ();

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedin']   = true; // indica que fez login
    $_SESSION['username']   = $user;
    $_SESSION['user_id']    = $registo['user_id'];

    $con->close();
    header("location: dashboard.php?PHPSESSID=" . session_id());

}

else {
        header("Location: Registo.php?erro='O user e a senha não existem na base de dados.'");
}

    ?>
```

As I was saying $result always returns 0 and I dont know why. PS: The names that I pass in POST method are correct and there are no errors showing up. I've done a " echo results; exit;" and it will always return 0. PSS: Im kinda new to php so it might be a stupid error but I can't really find a solving answer to it. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, not only is your connection vulnerable to SQL injection, but you're also using SHA1 for encryption, which is insecure in itself. Please consider switching to a more secure algorithm, and using parameterised queries to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: yes I will. Im just testing for now and I already had a more secured algorithm but since Ive went to youtube videos and web tutorials Ive changed a lot.

Comment: Try (just to see) :
$senha = sha1($senha);
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name
        FROM users
        WHERE user_name='$user' AND user_password = '$senha' ";

Comment: `$dbc->connect_errno` that for one thing, is using the wrong variable. Same for `die($dbc->error)`.

Comment: if it looks obvious but you are at a deadlock...break down the problem...as as TEST in development...remove the password part of the query...see if it returns your record...then youll know its the password is the problem (or vice versa)...if its the password...verify the sha hash matches whats in your database